J5 Images and Links 'Change Image' pop-up not displaying correctly on front-end for non-Cassiopeia template
I have a custom J5 template (not a Cassiopeia child). It has barely changed since I upgraded from its J4 version to J5. I normally do most of the editing on sites myself or my clients who use front-end editing generally insert images in the Content tab and not from the Images and Links tab. They also mostly use JCE Editor (Core).
I have just discovered that the pop-up that appears when clicking 'Select' for an image on an article Images and Links tab on the front end does not display correctly in J5.1.0 or 5.1.1. I was using JCE Editor (Core) and up until 5.0x it was working fine, when I was giving a Zoom tutorial to a front-end user who was supposed to be taking on some of my workload. Hah. When he tried to upload an image himself, he couldn't do it, but by this time the version was 5.1.0. It seems that JCE has changed some code. BUT, after disabling JCE and switching to TinyMCE, I discovered that I had the same issue, this time with both adding Media in the CMS Content dropdown in the Content tab and selecting images in the Images and Links tab, so it wasn't a JCE issue at all, but Joomla.
I installed several site backups going back in stages to early J4x to try and track down when this started. It didn't work in any of the backups. I have a J3 test site and the Images and Links pop-up shows perfectly on that custom template.
[Edit: I should also have said that what I am seeing is virtually nothing - the header is there, but the iframe is more or less empty. The head and body tags are there, but both are empty and no events are being triggered except a browser default:
]
How can I get around this? I'm tearing my hair out and wasting so much time and my new helper can't help me until I fix it. At the moment, I seem to have two options:

Recreate all my custom templates as children of Cassiopeia, with all the thousands of extra lines of (mainly CSS) code that that entails
Give my user limited backend access and have another training session.
Neither of these options are ideal.

Any suggestions very gratefully received.
Edit 2: below are screenshots showing the JS files that appear in the component iframe in first, Cassiopeia:

Second, my template (that event is a Firefox moz-extension) which is using a version of Cassiopeia's component.php.

-- End edit #2

Are there any relevant error messages shown when you look at the Console tab of the FireFox debug/Inspect in your image?

@Irata - absolutely none and I have full debug and error reporting on. I will add two more screenshots above which show the event files that are loaded in the component iframe in both Cassiopeia and my custom template.
